# How to Resolve Generic Class<T>(it's constructor parameter also generic...e.g:Param<T> param) With Unity Container?? help! thanks

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor, interface, unity-container

```
interface Interface<T>{}

class Class<T>:Interface<T>
{
      public Class(IInterfaceParam<T> param){}
}

interface IInterfaceParam<T>{}

class InterfaceParam<T>:IInterfaceParam<T>{}
```

how to config in unity.config xml file?

bellow is my config:

```
  <register type="IInterfaceParam`1" mapTo="InterfaceParam`1" name="paramDefault">
  </register>

  <register type="Interface`1" mapTo="Class`1">
    <constructor>
      <param type="IInterfaceParam`1" name="param">
        <dependency name="paramDefault"></dependency>
      </param>
    </constructor>
  </register>
```

but i got the exception:InvalidOperationException: Configuration is incorrect, the type Class`1 does not have a constructor that takes parameters named param. why?

Comment: You need to register a specific type, not a generic. `IInterfaceParam<object>`, not `IInterfaceParam<T>`.

Comment: thanks,i get...but still a little confused,i will try again ^_^@howcheng